# How to get the latest request in model Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

My Code:

```
$filter = Products::select(DB::raw('SUM(price) as `total_price`')
                            DB::raw('SUM(count) as `total_count`')
                            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m/%Y') new_date"),
                            DB::raw('YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month'))
                ->groupBy('year', 'month')
                ->get();

    $result = [];
    $total_price = 0;
    $total_count = 0;
    $new_date = null;

    foreach($filter as $f){
        $new_date = $f->new_date;
        $total_price = $f->total_price;
        $total_count = $f->total_count;
    }
```

*note : please use **dd($f)** , 
it will display total price, total count, and new date but it always the latest ones that shown

example:

```
if i input price and count at 02-08-2018 first
   i input price and count at 02-08-2020 second,
   i input price and count at 02-08-2016 third,
it will show the latest date which is all the data in 02-08-2020
```

what i want is, it will show according to the latest submit or input, which we can get by the latest **request** in form,

if we look at the example, the expected result should be all the data at **02-08-2016** .

Can anyone help me please????

Comment: you can use orderby https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: @GauravGupta if i use orderBy, is it going to return the latest request i input? i only know that if we use orderBy it going to return whether its asc or desc, and thats not what i want

Comment: Can't you add timestamps to your model? Then you can order by the `created_at` field.

Comment: @Jackowski i already have timestamp, but when i use the query above, it doesn't return it, i already try it before